# How can I set the daterangepicker to today + 1 day?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to set the startdate of my daterangepicker to `today + 1 day` and the enddate of my daterangepicker to `today + 2 days`.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var date = new Date();
                var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
                var currentDate = date.getDate();
                var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
                $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
                    , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    , startDate: +1
                    , endDate: +2
                    , locale: {
                        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

my result is `09.08.2017 - 09.08.2017`

But I expect `10.08.2017 - 11.08.2017`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in these lines:

```
, startDate: +1
, endDate: +2
```

Change to:

```
 , startDate: moment(date).add(1,'days')
 , endDate: moment(date).add(2,'days')
```

The snippet:

```js
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
var currentDate = date.getDate();
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
    , dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    , startDate: moment(date).add(1,'days')
    , endDate: moment(date).add(2,'days')
    , locale: {
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
```